# React - onSelect function not working of react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I used 'react-bootstrap'  in my application. I used [Tab Component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/). I want onSelect function of tabs component.

Below is my code for the component

```
export default class Users extends Component {
  handleSelect() {
    console.log("Tab selected")    
  } 

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="welcome-wrap">
        <br />
        <div className="row">
          <h3>Users</h3>
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} animation={false} id="user-role-tab">
            <Tab eventKey={1} title="Root Users" className="
            " onSelect={this.handleSelect()}>
              <RootUser/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={2} title="Organization Users" onSelect={this.handleSelect()}>
              <OrganizationUser/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={3} title="Business Users" onSelect={this.handleSelect()}>
              <BusinessUser/>
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It's working when the component is loaded but when I click on any tab the function is not called. I checked the solution of [How to call an event on tabs changed in react-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214548/how-to-call-an-event-on-tabs-changed-in-react-bootstrap) but it's also not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the `react-bootstrap` documentation. `onSelect` is a property of `Tabs`, not `Tab`. Like this:

```
<Tabs
    activeKey={this.state.key}
    onSelect={this.handleSelect} //For Tabs
    id="controlled-tab-example"
>
    <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">
        Tab 1 content
        </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">
        Tab 2 content
        </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3" disabled>
        Tab 3 content
        </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Refer https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not binding your function in constructor and the function can be called without (). These () are required when you want to pass some params otherwise not needed

Check below code for better understanding.

ES5:

```
export default class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }
  handleSelect() {
    console.log("Tab selected")    
  } 

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="welcome-wrap">
        <br />
        <div className="row">
          <h3>Users</h3>
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} animation={false} id="user-role-tab">
            <Tab eventKey={1} title="Root Users" className="
            " onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
              <RootUser/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={2} title="Organization Users" onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
              <OrganizationUser/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={3} title="Business Users" onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
              <BusinessUser/>
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

ES6: binding not required if use arrow function

```
export default class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
  }
  handleSelect = () => {
    console.log("Tab selected")    
  } 

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="welcome-wrap">
        <br />
        <div className="row">
          <h3>Users</h3>
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} animation={false} id="user-role-tab">
            <Tab eventKey={1} title="Root Users" className="
            " onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
              <RootUser/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={2} title="Organization Users" onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
              <OrganizationUser/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={3} title="Business Users" onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
              <BusinessUser/>
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the `class` syntax sugar was introduced in ES6 as well.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Sorry I am not getting that. Can you please elaborate your question

Comment: You've labelled binding within a class constructor as "ES5". Classes and constructors were introduced in ES6. The difference between binding in the constructor and using an arrow function is merely a difference of personal preference, and not a case of one being outdated compared to the other.

Comment: I do agree. Thank you. My ES5 and ES6 comparison is specific to only event handler function.

Comment: This was what I was missing, thanks for helping me understand!

Answer (score 2):

Where you have braces after the function name, you're calling the function when assigning it to the `onSelect` property.

You can either bind the function in your constructor and directly use `this.handleSelect`:

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <Tab onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
  )
}
```

Or wrap it in an anonymous function:

```html
<Tab onSelect={(event) => this.handleSelect(event)}>
```

---

Based on the [react-bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/), however, `onSelect` is not a property the `<Tab/>` component accepts, instead it should be placed on the wrapping `<Tabs/>` component.